# spring security - 403 forbidden and not call loadUserByUsername()

Tags: spring, spring-security, web-config

I added spring security to my app. I would like to secure any endpoints, and open "/users" for all
User configuration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    public UserEntity(UserCreateRequestModel userCreateRequestModel) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.login = userCreateRequestModel.getLogin();
        this.password = PasswordService.codePassword(userCreateRequestModel.getPassword());
        this.role = "USER";
    }

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    return new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return login;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

My custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users", "/users/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority("USER")
            ;
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and next I added custom UserDetailsService

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
private final UserEntityRepository userEntityRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(userEntityRepository.findByLogin(login));
    return userEntityRepository.findByLogin(login).orElseThrow((() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(login)));
}
```

and now I am getting problem. Endpoint for "/users" is open to all, I can send request with any problem. But when I am trying for example any @PostMapping on endpoint "/shapes"
I am getting 403 status response. In postman I think everything is OK:
[image: postmanView]

of course user exists in database. In UserEntity user isEnabled, isAccountNonExpired, isAccountNonLocked and isCredentialsNonExpired - everything is on true.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getAuthorities()` method of `UserEntity` class you're returning an **empty** `List`, so spring-security sees no authorities (roles) for an authenticated user.

Change this method like this:

```java
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
}
```